# jQuery custom content scroller scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've done scroll bar with `jQuery custom content scroller` just fine , but have some problems with it. Exactly I've done this scroll bar with div tag in which I'm retrieving data from mysql (some posts), so my problem is that I'm using ajax for sending data to database and it works too ,but when data is appended on div tag , scroller has fixed size , it isn't renewing (only renewing when page is refreshed). How can renew scroll bar size within adding data with ajax ? And also I can't understand how it is possible to fix scroll bar at the end ? pls help I'm very confused about this issue , thanks :)

PS. here is plugin home page too http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

**UPDATE**

```
$.ajax({
                url:  "ajax/posting.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {send_post: "Send", user_id: "<?php echo $userArr[0]; ?>", user_name: "<?php echo $userArr[2] . " " . $userArr[3]; ?>", msg: $("#post").val()},
                complete: function(){
                    $("#post").val("");
                },
                success: function(result){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:  "ajax/posting.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {renew_posts: "Yes",admin: "<?php echo $userArr[1]; ?>",owner: "<?php echo $userArr[0]; ?>"},
                        success: function(renewed_data){
                            $("#chat_tb").html(renewed_data);
                            (function($){$(window).load(function(){$(".post_container").mCustomScrollbar({
                                scrollButtons:{enable:true,scrollSpeed: 40}
                            });});})(jQuery);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

In this code only it is remarkable how to update mCustomScrollbar() function within callback , after sending data to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Fluid scrollbar demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/fluid_scrollbar_example.html).

**EDIT**

If that don't works try to reinitialize the `.mCustomScrollbar()`-functon after your ajax request.

**EDIT 2**

Just a try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/posting.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        send_post: "Send",
        user_id: "<?php echo $userArr[0]; ?>",
        user_name: "<?php echo $userArr[2] . "" . $userArr[3]; ?>",
        msg: $("#post").val()
    },
    complete: function() {
        $("#post").val("");
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/posting.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                renew_posts: "Yes",
                admin: "<?php echo $userArr[1]; ?>",
                owner: "<?php echo $userArr[0]; ?>"
            },
            success: function(renewed_data) {
                $("#chat_tb").html(renewed_data);
                $(".post_container").mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollButtons: {
                        enable: true,
                        scrollSpeed: 40
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

Comment: I've posted myself this page, just posted question because can't understand how to do that

Comment: it must be written withing ajax success script yes ?

Comment: And Also I've read documentations but I guess can't understand how to fix it at the end by default , is it possible ?

Comment: Yes and No, you need to do it as a callback function. Take a Look at **context**: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It is much easier for us to help you, if you give us a small code snippet ;-) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: so it is not possible to fix it at the end yes ?